# How to make a cut off time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

I want to round off the time like `01:00:00` or `01:30:00` or `02:00:00` or `02:30:00` or `03:00:00`

TABLE1

```
ID TIME

001 02:15:00 'Format (HH:mm:ss)
002 02:17:00
003 02:47:00
004 03:00:00
005 02:00:00
....
```

`Time` column's datatype is `nvarchar`

Condition

```
02:00:00 to 02:15:00 - I want to show 02:00:00 only
02:16:00 to 02:44:00 - I want to show 02:30:00 only
02:45:00 to 03:00:00 - I want to show 03:00:00 only
...
```

Expected output for table1

```
ID TIME

001 02:00:00 'Less than or equal to 2.15 mins so it should change to 02 hrs
002 02:30:00 'Less than 2.44 mins so it should change to 2.30 mins
003 03:00:00 'Greather than 2.45 mins so it should change to 03 hrs
004 03:00:00 'Same
005 02:00:00 'Same
....
```

How to make a query for this condition

Need query help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
CREATE TABLE #time(ID int, TIME nvarchar(25))

INSERT INTO #time
VALUES(001,'02:15:00'),
(002,'02:17:00'),
(003,'02:47:00'),
(004,'03:00:00'),
(005,'02:00:00')

SELECT time,CASE  
             WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(time,CHARINDEX(':',time,1)+1,2) as int) <= 15 then LEFT(time,2)+':00:00'
             WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(time,CHARINDEX(':',time,1)+1,2) as int) >15 and CAST(SUBSTRING(time,CHARINDEX(':',time,1)+1,2) as int) <=45 then LEFT(time,2)+':30:00' 
             WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(time,CHARINDEX(':',time,1)+1,2) as int) >45 and CAST(SUBSTRING(time,CHARINDEX(':',time,1)+1,2) as int) <=59 then '0'+cast((cast(LEFT(time,2) as int)+1) as varchar(3))+':00:00' 
             END
FROM #time
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time VARCHAR(8), @RoundTo float)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RoundedTime smalldatetime
   DECLARE @Multiplier float

   SET @Multiplier= 24.0/@RoundTo

   SET @RoundedTime= ROUND(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(varchar,@Time,121) AS datetime) AS float) * @Multiplier,0)/@Multiplier

   RETURN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),@RoundedTime,108)
END



--select dbo.roundtime('02:47:00',0.5)
```

**In a single statement**

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),dateadd(mi, (datediff(mi,0,'02:47:00')+29)/30*30, 0),108)
```

Comment: can you suggest some easy method instead of writing a function, bcoz already my query is complicated

Comment: You can not do it in a single statement. Better keep it as a function so that your original code will be more readable.

Comment: Yes. You can do it in a single statement. Read my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
convert(char(8), dateadd(minute, ((14+datediff(minute, 0, cast(Time as datetime)))/30)*30, 0), 108) as Time
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75652)

Answer (score 0):

Also try this

```
select 
    id,
    time,
    convert(varchar(10),dateadd(minute,datediff
        (
        minute,
        case when hours<=15 then -15 when hours>15 then 15  else 0 end,
        time)/30*30,0) ,108)
    as cut_off_time
from
(
    select id,time,
        datepart(minute,cast(time as datetime)) as hours from #time
) as t
```